# How do I create following IIS structure using InstallShield

Tags: iis, installshield

I need to create the following structure in InstallShield (Basic MSI Project).

DefaultWebSite
-MyWebsite
--Entities\MyWebsite
--Entities\Workflow\MyWebsite
--Workflow\MyWebsite

Once again, the above structure is in IIS, after installation.

How do I replicate the above structure in InstallShield?

When trying to define a website like this "Entities\MyWebsite", the "'\" was removed as it is an incorrect character.

[image: IIS]

Answer (score 0):

In Application Data ⇒ Files and Folders

you create the New Folders *Entities*, *MyWebsite*, etc.

**Level by level**, so the backslash is not part of the name.